# How do I list the yum repo that a package is a part of?

Tags: linux, centos, yum

When I run the command `yum erase $(rpm -qa |grep gnome)`, I get the following output:

```
========================================================================================================================
 Package                          Arch        Version               Repository                                     Size
========================================================================================================================
Removing:
 gnome-backgrounds                noarch      2.28.0-2.el6          @anaconda-CentOS-201303020151.x86_64/6.4      9.5 M
 gnome-bluetooth-libs             x86_64      2.28.6-8.el6          @anaconda-CentOS-201303020151.x86_64/6.4      165 k
 gnome-doc-utils-stylesheets      noarch      0.18.1-1.el6          @anaconda-CentOS-201303020151.x86_64/6.4      1.3 M
```

What I want to do is list out all of the items in the "Repository" column for all packages on my system and/or do a query for all packages in the "@anaconda-CentOS-201303020151.x86_64/6.4" repository. Any of the "repo" options in yum that I can see only list base, epel, etc., and `yum repolist all` doesn't mention "@anaconda-CentOS-201303020151.x86_64/6.4" at all. So how do I see it and what's in it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`yum list installed | grep -F "anaconda-CentOS-201303020151.x86_64/6.4"`

Comment: Oddly enough, piping the output formatted it in a way that gave potentially bad results, but the simple `yum list installed` formatted the output properly, so I got what I wanted.

Comment: Does that list every package installed, or only the "main" packages and not dependencies (that have to be installed along with the main one)

Comment: AFAIK, it list every package, even dependencies and such.

Comment: Same for almost all of the deb tools too, unfortunately